# operator == list of pointers googleTest c++

Tags: c++, list, operators, googletest

I'm trying to compare two **lists of pointers** via googletest, and everytime I do that my test stops running at that test block. it doesn't give me an error or something, just stops.
here is my code:

```
TEST_F(WorkerTest, checkCtor)
{

Worker oved(m_id,m_job,m);
EXPECT_EQ(oved.getId(),m_id);
EXPECT_TRUE(m_job == oved.getJob() );
EXPECT_TRUE(m == oved.getMoviesOfWorker()); //PROBLEMATIC LINE

}
```

here is my code for getMoviesOfWorker:

```
list<Movie*> Worker::getMoviesOfWorker(){

 std::list<Movie*> m;
 return m;
}
```

my constructor of Worker looks like this:

```
Worker(int m_id, std::string m_job, std::list<Movie*> moviesToWorker){};
```

and my WorkerTest class looks like this:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Worker.h"
#include <list>

class WorkerTest : public ::testing::Test {

protected:

int sizeBefore;
std::list<Movie*> m;
std::string m_job;
int m_id;
virtual void SetUp(){};
virtual void TearDown(){};

public:
WorkerTest() : sizeBefore(), m(), m_id(), m_job(){}
};
```

I don't understand in general why would googleTest stop, and btw I don't have implementation for any of my functions (getId or getJob), and even when I do return some list in getMoviesOfWorker() it still crashes.. HELP?

Comment: wtf I don't get it : `and btw I don't have implementation for any of my functions (getId or getJob)` so how is your code supposed to work ?

Comment: googleTest works it out without the implementation.. it always returns default values and it fails tests (as i expect), if it works out for getId() without implementation it has to work out for the other functions

Comment: I don't know much about googleTest but when I write Tests, I implement the methods, functions I call...

Comment: You do have some implementation (maybe empty) for `getId` and `getJob` or your test wouldn't compile. Please, edit your question to include `Worker` code, at least a sketch of the current implementation for `getMoviesOfWorker` since that is the *problematic* line.

Comment: I implemented something just so you see, and added it here.
it still doesnt continue the test

Comment: Post a complete example we can test.